# Rails calls unexpected controller action instead of redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I believe is the most bizarre bug in my rails app.

What my app does is allows you to sign up.  After you sign up it sends you an activation email with a link to activate your account. The link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/24932b7edf2e7cc7c9e8e51b8e7a7f75a88016f9/activate
```

and the route looks like this:

```
activate        /users/:activation_code/activate(.:format) users#activate
```

You click the link, and it calls the activate method in the users controller, which looks like this:

```
def activate
  @user = User.find_by_activation_code(params[:activation_code])
  if @user.nil?
    flash[:error] = "User not found or already activated. Try logging in"
  else
    @user.activate
    flash[:success] = "User successfully activated"
  end
  redirect_to login_path
end
```

This is where it gets fuzzy. Instead of redirecting to `login_path`, the app tries to call a different action in the users controller, and the rails app chokes.  I just cannot for the life of me understand what is happening.  It tries to redirect to the `location` action in the users controller instead of to the `login_path`, and then fails with the error `Couldn't find User without an ID`.  The `location` action looks like this:

```
def location
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and it naturally fails because in this case there is no :id parameter in the URL.  Here's the relevant part of the stack trace.  Line 130 is the call to redirect, then it calls the location action.

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:38:in `location'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:130:in `activate'
```

If I remove or comment the `redirect_to login_path`, then it doesn't try to call the location method in my users controller, and falls back on the view for the activate action, which doesn't exist.  Here are my routes:

```
location_user GET    /users/:id/location(.:format)              users#location
login                /login(.:format)                           sessions#new
```

Does anybody have an ideas?

EDIT: Pasting Log entries

```
Processing by UsersController#activate as HTML
  Parameters: {"activation_code"=>"24932b7edf2e7cc7c9e8e51b8e7a7f75a88016f9"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`activation_code` = '24932b7edf2e7cc7c9e8e51b8e7a7f75a88016f9' LIMIT 1
Redirected to 
Completed 404 Not Found in 29.4ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:38:in `location'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:130:in `activate'
```

Comment: Could you paste the entire controller? If you are using Devise here, you could also check the after_sign_in_path_for type helpers.

Comment: Looks alright to me @MoDiggity... could you check logs for "halted"? I don't remember the correct wording but I believe it's something like "before filter chain halted". Maybe you have a filter in your ApplicationController redirecting to that action?

Comment: I pasted in the error log, which i forgot in the original post.  There is nothing going on in the application controller.  Anybody else have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems to have been an issue with the name of the action :location

When I changed `def location` to `def map`, everything works fine now.

I hope that this helps somebody at some point!